# Help to draw an arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw a red arrow to make it look like the rest of the arrows in the picture?
How to define the parameters for the red arrow: line thickness, width, start and end?
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, trees, positioning, arrows, shapes, shapes.multipart, shadows, matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, transform shape, >=stealth', on grid, node distance=5.2em, ultra thick,
cyl1/.style={color=black, cylinder, draw, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.15, text width=5.5em, minimum height=6.5em, minimum width=2em, align=center}]
\node[rectangle, draw, minimum height=14em, minimum width=7em, align=center](obj_u){\textbf{Xxxxxx}\\\textbf{xxxxxxxxxx}};
%
\node[cyl1, xshift=16.9em, yshift=4em, right=of obj_u](xfd){xxxx xxxx xxxx};
\node[cyl1, xshift=16.9em, yshift=-4em, right=of obj_u](xed){xxxx xxxx xxxx};
%
\node[single arrow, draw, align=center, xshift=10.5em, yshift=4em, rotate=0, minimum height=14em](potok1){xxxx xxxx\\xxxx xxxx};
\node[single arrow, draw, align=center, xshift=10.5em, yshift=-4em, rotate=0, minimum height=14em](potok2){xxxx xxxx\\xxxx xxxx};
%
\node[rectangle, draw, minimum height=14em, minimum width=4em, align=center, xshift=30em, right=of obj_u](glpr){\textbf{XXXX}};
%
\node[double arrow, draw, align=center, xshift=1.9em, rotate=0, minimum width=2.5em, right=of xfd](inf1){Xxxxxxxxxx};
\node[double arrow, draw, align=center, xshift=1.9em, rotate=0, minimum width=2.5em, right=of xed](inf2){Xxxxxxxxxx};
%
\draw[line width=2ex, -triangle 60, red, 
        postaction={draw, color=white,line width=1.5ex,shorten >=.25ex,shorten <=.5ex}]
        (glpr.north) -- ($(glpr.north) + (0,3em)$) -| (obj_u.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, trees, positioning, arrows, shapes, shapes.multipart, shadows, matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, transform shape, >=stealth', on grid, node distance=5.2em, ultra thick, cyl1/.style={color=black, cylinder, draw, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.15, text width=5.5em, minimum height=6.5em, minimum width=2em, align=center}]
\node[rectangle, draw, minimum height=14em, minimum width=7em, align=center](obj_u){\textbf{Xxxxxx}\\\textbf{xxxxxxxxxx}};
%
\node[cyl1, xshift=16.9em, yshift=4em, right=of obj_u](xfd){xxxx xxxx xxxx};
\node[cyl1, xshift=16.9em, yshift=-4em, right=of obj_u](xed){xxxx xxxx xxxx};
%
\node[single arrow, draw, align=center, xshift=10.5em, yshift=4em, rotate=0, minimum height=14em](potok1){xxxx xxxx\\xxxx xxxx};
\node[single arrow, draw, align=center, xshift=10.5em, yshift=-4em, rotate=0, minimum height=14em](potok2){xxxx xxxx\\xxxx xxxx};
%
\node[rectangle, draw, minimum height=14em, minimum width=4em, align=center, xshift=30em, right=of obj_u](glpr){\textbf{XXXX}};
%
\node[double arrow, draw, align=center, xshift=1.9em, rotate=0, minimum width=2.5em, right=of xfd](inf1){Xxxxxxxxxx};
\node[double arrow, draw, align=center, xshift=1.9em, rotate=0, minimum width=2.5em, right=of xed](inf2){Xxxxxxxxxx};
%
\draw[line width=1.5ex,-triangle 60, red,
    postaction={draw,color=white,line width=0.01\linewidth,shorten >=.6ex,shorten <=.4ex}]
    (glpr.north) -- ($(glpr.north) + (0,4em)$) -| (obj_u.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and its output:

[image]

Comment: It looks bad. A red arrow has a different line thickness!
Maybe there is a better way to draw these arrows?

Comment: @Youra_P, I've made little improvement. Please see if it is ok.