# Arrow-shaped text boxes (for use in ipe vector graphics editor)?

Tags: boxes, arrows, matplotlib, ipe

### Ipe vector graphics editor

I am currently evaluating the [`ipe` vector graphics editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipe_%28program%29). A very attractive feature is that [one can use LaTeX-commands inside its text objects](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/manual/manual_17.html) as long as these are legal inside a `\makebox` (for labels) or inside a minipage (for minipages). However, one cannot use commands that involve a non-linear translation into PDF, such as commands to generate hyperlinks or to include external images.
Nonetheless, LaTeX-commands that are defined in additional LaTeX packages can be included with a `\usepackage` command in the LaTeX preamble, which can be set in `Document properties` under the `Edit` menu.

### Question

What I am looking for is a way to enclose text inside a left or right arrow-shaped box with LaTeX-commands in `ipe`? A simple LaTeX package that would create text boxes much like `rarrow` and `larrow` of the [`BoxStyle` class in `matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.BoxStyle) (see below specimen) would do just fine. Other techniques are welcome too. LibreOffice Impress and PowerPoint also offer such arrow shapes with text, even curved ones.

### Attempts

1. Drawing an `\fbox` around a text object in `ipe` works flawlessly. Even a rotated `\ovalbox` with math constitutes no problem with `\usepackage{rotating, fancybox}` in the preamble. There are no arrows in [`fancybox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancybox), though.
2. I looked for a LaTeX package providing arrow-shaped boxes among [the packages listed among "boxing" on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/topic/boxing). Perhaps I am looking over it, but no such package appears to be listed.
3. Everybody here seems to use TikZ arrows, so I tried [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58510/inserting-text-inside-an-arrow-in-tikz) and [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73733/help-to-draw-an-arrow-in-tikz) inside `ipe`. The result of these failed TikZ experiments is shown in the bottom image. It fails because of the `ipe` LaTeX text object limitations mentioned earlier.

### matplotlib Boxstyle specimen

[image: matplotlib Boxstyle specimen]

### Rotated ovalbox in ipe

[image: rotated ovalbox in ipe]

### TikZ arrows do not work in ipe

[image: TikZ arrows do not work in ipe]

Comment: There is a TikZ library `shapes.arrows`. Then `\node[single arrow, draw] (a) {Arrow};` typesets the word `Arrow` in an arrow shaped box, but I'm pretty sure this won't work in `ipe`.

Comment: @HenriMenke TikZ is what I tried, but indeed it does not work in `ipe`. I am just amazed that there seems to be nothing else but TikZ to place text in an arrow...

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is also something for `pstricks`, but this won't work in `ipe` either ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an "arrow box" macro based on LaTeX picture mode. Maybe this will work for you?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\ab@texttotalheight
\newdimen\ab@arrowstemwidth
\newdimen\ab@arrowheadwidth
\newdimen\ab@arrowwidth
\newdimen\ab@arrowstemheight
\newdimen\ab@arrowheight
\newcommand\rightarrowbox{\@arrowbox+}
\newcommand\leftarrowbox{\@arrowbox-}
\newcommand\@arrowbox[2]
{%
  \begingroup
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{#2}%
    \ab@texttotalheight\dimexpr\ht\@tempboxa+\dp\@tempboxa\relax
    \ab@arrowstemwidth\dimexpr\wd\@tempboxa\relax
    \ab@arrowheadwidth\dimexpr2\fboxsep+.5\ab@texttotalheight\relax
    \ab@arrowwidth\dimexpr\ab@arrowstemwidth+\ab@arrowheadwidth\relax
    \ab@arrowstemheight\dimexpr2\fboxsep+\ab@texttotalheight\relax
    \ab@arrowheight\dimexpr4\fboxsep+\ab@texttotalheight\relax
    \thicklines
    \unitlength\p@
    \edef\@temp{{picture}(\strip@pt\ab@arrowwidth,\strip@pt\ab@arrowheight)\if#1-(-\strip@pt\ab@arrowwidth,0)\fi}%
    \expandafter\raisebox\expandafter{\the\dimexpr-\dp\@tempboxa-2\fboxsep\relax}
    {%
    \expandafter\begin\@temp
      \put(#1\strip@pt\@halfwidth,\strip@pt\fboxsep){\line(0,1){\strip@pt\ab@arrowstemheight}}
      \@tempdima\dimexpr2\fboxsep+\dp\@tempboxa\relax
      \@tempdimb\if#1-\dimexpr\fboxsep+\wd\@tempboxa\relax\else\fboxsep\fi\relax
      \put(#1\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdima){\box\@tempboxa}
      \@tempdima\dimexpr3\fboxsep+\ab@texttotalheight\relax
      \@tempdimb\dimexpr\ab@arrowstemwidth+\@halfwidth\relax
      \put(0,\strip@pt\@tempdima){\line(#11,0){\strip@pt\@tempdimb}}
      \put(0,\strip@pt\fboxsep){\line(#11,0){\strip@pt\@tempdimb}}
      \put(#1\strip@pt\ab@arrowstemwidth,\strip@pt\@tempdima){\line(0,1){\strip@pt\fboxsep}}
      \put(#1\strip@pt\ab@arrowstemwidth,0){\line(0,1){\strip@pt\fboxsep}}
      \advance\@tempdima\fboxsep
      \put(#1\strip@pt\ab@arrowstemwidth,\strip@pt\@tempdima){\line(#11,-1){\strip@pt\ab@arrowheadwidth}}
      \put(#1\strip@pt\ab@arrowstemwidth,0){\line(#11,1){\strip@pt\ab@arrowheadwidth}}
    \end{picture}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}

\leftarrowbox{\Large\textsf{foo}} \rightarrowbox{\Large\textsf{foo}}
\fbox{\Large\textsf{foo}}

\bigskip

\leftarrowbox{\Large\textsf{goo}} \rightarrowbox{\Large\textsf{goo}} 
\fbox{\Large\textsf{goo}}

\bigskip
\leftarrowbox{\Large\textsf{\strut foo}} \rightarrowbox{\Large\textsf{\strut goo}} 

\bigskip

\leftarrowbox{\Large\textsf{\begin{tabular}{l}foo\\goo\end{tabular}}}
\rightarrowbox{\Large\textsf{\begin{tabular}{l}foo\\goo\end{tabular}}}
\fbox{\Large\textsf{\begin{tabular}{l}foo\\goo\end{tabular}}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Example output]

**EDIT**

As OP, I have added above preamble to `ipe`, together with an additional `\usepackage{rotating}`. The `ipe` text object only contains the following in order to generate the tilted text arrow:

```
\begin{turn}{56}
  \rightarrowbox{\Large\textbf{yahoo!}}
\end{turn}
```

[image: tilted text arrow]

Comment: As for myself and me uses, this is exactly why I'm glad technologies like TikZ, PSTricks, and Metapost actually exist.  +1 for extreme effort!  You might want to add a strut though to account for the 'varying' baseline between `foo` and `goo`.

Comment: @SeanAllred I challenge you to run both my solution and a TikZ "arrow box" with `\tracingall` active and then report which of those represents "extreme effort" (put `\tracingall` after the `\documentclass` command to also catch package loading :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred The idea was to make it similar to `\fbox` which also behaves like this. Also, if you use it with a table or `\parbox`, the `\strut` might get in the way. Speaking of which, maybe I should lower the picture so the text sits on the baseline, to make it even more like `\fbox`. But first I'll need some evidence someone would use it :-)

Comment: Haha! Well, I'm fine with the *computer* putting forth a reasonable effort :) And I imagine trying to make this solution more and more robust is just going to end in sadness.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt I have edited the code to remove the glitches. However, I think from a LaTeX consistency perspective it's really better to be as near to `\fbox` as possible. I don't understand your spacing argument. The space above "f" and below "g" are equal, aren't they?

Comment: @StephanLehmke It would be great if this could be poured into a package or, even better, merged with the fancybox package.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt To me it looks a bit flimsy to make a separate package. You'll probably be the only user anyway, because it's useful exactly for the one case you're having. So at least one other person should ask for it ;-)

Comment: @StephanLehmke I checked [the `fancybox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox); it is also applying the `\fbox` spacing rule. Perhaps you would be willing to cede the code to that project with due attribution? This would be great for the users and would spare you the packaging effort.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Perhaps you should also add 'foo' & 'goo' examples with `\strut` in front. Just to show what is possible for people who ―like myself― only learn at this instance what a `\strut` is for.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt I see you have already acted on what I was going to suggest: As everything posted here is published under CC license, you're free to contribute the code yourself (which I hereby explicitly give permission to :-)