# Can I have tikz nodes formed as arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I know that I can make nodes that are squares or circles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (foo) [draw] {foo};
        \node [draw, circle, right of=foo] {bar};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would like a node that has the form of an arrow pointing to the right. In this case so that the foo node points towards the bar node.

How can I easily do this? Is there some library or such with fancy node shapes perhaps?

Comment: See also: [Help to draw an arrow in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73733/4778)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shapes.arrows` is what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, single arrow] (foo) {foo};
        \node [draw, circle, right = 0pt of foo] {bar};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```